# Getting weird values for a statistical test in python

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, jupyter-notebook, definition

I'm trying to perform a Mann-Kendall Test of some data. I'm using the code in the following link (https://github.com/mps9506/Mann-Kendall-Trend/blob/master/mk_test.py) modified a little bit bellow for the result to be in an array and it only gives back a p-value (p) and a tau value (z).

```
def mk_test(x, alpha=0.05):
    """
    This function is derived from code originally posted by Sat Kumar Tomer
    (satkumartomer@gmail.com)
    See also: http://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/Vsample/Design_Trend_Mann_Kendall.htm
    The purpose of the Mann-Kendall (MK) test (Mann 1945, Kendall 1975, Gilbert
    1987) is to statistically assess if there is a monotonic upward or downward
    trend of the variable of interest over time. A monotonic upward (downward)
    trend means that the variable consistently increases (decreases) through
    time, but the trend may or may not be linear. The MK test can be used in
    place of a parametric linear regression analysis, which can be used to test
    if the slope of the estimated linear regression line is different from
    zero. The regression analysis requires that the residuals from the fitted
    regression line be normally distributed; an assumption not required by the
    MK test, that is, the MK test is a non-parametric (distribution-free) test.
    Hirsch, Slack and Smith (1982, page 107) indicate that the MK test is best
    viewed as an exploratory analysis and is most appropriately used to
    identify stations where changes are significant or of large magnitude and
    to quantify these findings.
    Input:
        x:   a vector of data
        alpha: significance level (0.05 default)
    Output:
        trend: tells the trend (increasing, decreasing or no trend)
        h: True (if trend is present) or False (if trend is absence)
        p: p value of the significance test
        z: normalized test statistics`

    Examples
    --------
      >>> x = np.random.rand(100)
      >>> trend,h,p,z = mk_test(x,0.05)
    """
    n = len(x)

    # calculate S
    s = 0
    for k in range(n-1):
        for j in range(k+1, n):
            s += np.sign(x[j] - x[k])

    # calculate the unique data
    unique_x = np.unique(x)
    g = len(unique_x)

    # calculate the var(s)
    if n == g:  # there is no tie
        var_s = (n*(n-1)*(2*n+5))/18
    else:  # there are some ties in data
        tp = np.zeros(unique_x.shape)
        for i in range(len(unique_x)):
            tp[i] = sum(x == unique_x[i])
        var_s = (n*(n-1)*(2*n+5) - np.sum(tp*(tp-1)*(2*tp+5)))/18

    if s > 0:
        z = (s - 1)/np.sqrt(var_s)
        #result = (s - 1)/np.sqrt(var_s)
    elif s == 0:
         z = 0
        #result = 0
    elif s < 0:
        z = (s + 1)/np.sqrt(var_s)
        #result = (s + 1)/np.sqrt(var_s)

    # calculate the p_value
    p = 2*(1-norm.cdf(abs(z)))  # two tail test
    result= np.append(p,z)
    h = abs(z) > norm.ppf(1-alpha/2)

    return np.array(result)
```

I am then using the following code to perform the test.

```
out = np.empty((0))
for i in range(145):
    for j in range(192):
        out1 = mk_test(yrmax[:,i,j], alpha=0.05)
        out = np.append(out, out1, axis=0)
```

I think something is going wrong somewhere while performing the test because I would expect to get z values between -1 and 1, but I'm getting back some values that are greater than 1. Is the coding going wrong or am I misunderstanding what z is and it's not actually tau and hence why I'm getting values I'm not expecting?

Comment: If this question is about the calcuation/implementation of your statistic, you might have better luck at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was something going wrong with the coding or not. I'll post it there too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a statistical issue, but on stackexchange I was offered a solution to modify this code in order to get Kendall-Tau values instead of z-values. They also explain what a z-value and as long as this question is here I'll provide the link for anyone that makes a similar mistake.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311061/getting-weird-values-for-a-statistical-test-in-python